# Multiplying columns with factor

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a matrix

```
matrix=Table[RandomInteger[],{i,3},{j,3}]
```

And I multiply it with

```
vector={1,3,5}
```

All three rows change accordingly.

What do I have to do, when I want to change the columns? Is this:

```
Transpose@matrix*vector//Transpose
```

the shortest solution, or do you have better ideas? Because

```
matrix*Transpose@vector
```

does not work.

Comment: I think the transpose is a good solution.  This also works: `vector # & /@ matrix`.

Comment: `matrix.DiagonalMatrix[vector]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will multiply the `vector` by each row of `matrix` individually:

```
vector # & /@ matrix
```

and give the same result as

```
Transpose[matrix] vector // Transpose
```

Edit:  To get rid of all the useful shorthand to see what is going on underneath, this is identical to what I wrote above:

```
Map[Function[Times[vector, #]], matrix]
```

Comment: So "applying a number" onto a number in mathematica is the short version for the function multiplication. `vector * # & /@ matrix` would be the pure way?

Comment: And thank you very much!

Comment: I like to not use the `*` for multiplication, it muddles things up.  You are applying a function `vector #` - which multiplies `vector` by the argument, to the list `matrix`, whose elements are the rows.

Comment: Its just to make things clearer for me. I do not want to make so much use of implicit notation in the beginning. Especially now it is easier for me to understand how to make division `#/ vector  & /@ matrix`. And that the application of a number as a function is defined implicitly as multiplication is just Mathematica, it could also be defined as + or something like that. At least I think so.

Comment: Personally, I would use `matrix.DiagonalMatrix[vector]` (as noted above).