# How do I put matrices next to each other?

Tags: matrix

So I want to be able to put matrices "next to each other", or in other words if I have two matrices $A$ that is  $n\times k$ and $B$ that is $n\times m$, I want to be able to create a matrix $C$ that is $n\times (k+m)$ so that the $(k+1)$th column of $C$ is the first column of $B$.

This should be really easy, and in matlab it is (C= [A B]), but I can't figure it out in mathematica

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/131. I suspect everything is already available there.

Comment: [ArrayFlatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
(a = ConstantArray["A", {4, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(b = ConstantArray["B", {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Map[Flatten, Transpose[{a, b}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: `Join[a, b, 2]`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!