# For loop works at top-level but not in a function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Why does this work:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[list][[1]], i++, list = Insert[list, i, {i, 3}]]
```

But this doesn't:

```
insertColumns[list_] :=  
  For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[list][[1]], i++, 
    list = Insert[list, i, {i, 3}]]
```

I get a message saying that something in the part assignment is not a symbol. But this:

```
insertColumns[list_] := 
  For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[list][[1]], i++,
    Return[FullForm[list[[i]]]]]
```

Returns this result:

```
List[1,"Red","Name","Random"]
```

I am very new to *Mathematica*, so please be kind :)

Comment: Try `insertColumns[list_ List]` to indicate a list is input.

Comment: That seems to get rid of the error messages, but just returns insertColumns[{the list of things I gave it}]

Comment: What is the input you're using? To reproduce the error you should let us know what list you actually used.

Comment: {{1, "Red", "Name", "Random"}, {1, "Red", "Tim", "asdfg"}}

So when I pass this to the function, it just returns:

insertColumns[{{1, "Red", "Name", "Random"}, {1, "Red", "Tim", "asdfg"}}]

Comment: With a slight modification it works - see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you use a `list` input that is appropriate for use with `Insert` as it appears in the function, you would only have to localize `list` to avoid further errors:

```
insertColumns[list_] := 
 Module[{l = list}, 
  For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[list][[1]], i++, 
   l = Insert[l, i, {i, 3}]]; l]

insertColumns[{{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}]

(* ==> {{a1, b1, 1, c1}, {a2, b2, 2, c2}, {a3, b3, 3, c3}} *)

insertColumns[{{1, "Red", "Name", "Random"}, {1, "Red", 
   "Tim", "asdfg"}}]

(*
==> {{1, "Red", 1, "Name", "Random"}, {1, "Red", 2, "Tim", 
  "asdfg"}}
*)
```

However, this entire approach is of course very un-*Mathematica*-like.

**Explanation**

The reason why you have to localize the variable `list` is that *Mathematica* uses what can be called "pass-by-value" in which the argument `list` is resolved into the actual list of entries. The dummy variable name `list` represents a function slot and is not actually a `Symbol` to which you should try to assign things. There is no need to know about this when you just extract values from `list` (as with the dimension in your code), but you get into trouble when actually trying to *assign* new values to the arguments named by the dummy variable `list`.

The assignment by `Set` (`=`) in the `For` loop sees a list structure on both sides of the equation, and attempts to `Thread` over it to make the assignment element-wise. But since the right-hand side is a modified version of `list` in which elements have been added, the dimensions of the lists in `Set` don't match. This causes an error.

The localized variable `l` is treated as a `Symbol` and not a "dummy variable", so `Set` doesn't try to match dimensions in that case. This is why the above code avoids the error.

The other issue is one of aesthetics and efficiency. In the `For` loop, the entire list is copied in every step. Also, simple iterations are often better done using special constructs that operate on `Lists` without explicitly introducing a counter index, as required in `For`. There is a lot of relevant information about this in the post [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/245). The `MapIndexed` approach in @m_goldberg's answer is mentioned there, too.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by un-Mathematica-like? I'd rather be working with the language than fighting it.

Comment: Also, could you clarify why my original code doesn't work inside the function, but this does?

Comment: OK, I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

As Jens says your approach is not very *Mathematica*-like, i.e., it doesn't make good use of *Mathematica*'s strengths. Here is an implementation that I hope Jens would agree makes better use of those strengths. Although it is more concise than your method, it has more generality; you can pick the column where the index of the list element is inserted.

```
insertIndex[data_List, col_Integer] /; 0 < col <= Length[data[[1]]] + 1 :=
  MapIndexed[Insert[#1, #2[[1]], col] &, data]
```

To digest this answer, you should look up [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) in the Documentation Center. The article under `Part` will explain the `[[ ]]` notation and article under `Function` will explain the `#1`, `#2`, and `&` stuff.

The rather elaborate formal argument pattern is designed restrict arguments to valid ones -- not perfectly, but usefully.

#### Testing

First I generate a list of 6 3-element lists.

```
data[n_] := With[{names = Alphabet[]}, Table[RandomSample[names, 3], n]]
SeedRandom[42]; test = data[6]
```

> `{{"n", "u", "e"}, {"c", "b", "g"}, {"a", "t", "e"}, 
>   {"d", "i", "m"}, {"a", "h", "i"}, {"w", "z", "g"}}`

Then I have `insertIndex` insert the index of each sublist at positions 1 to 4

```
Table[insertIndex[test, col], {col, Length[test[[1]]] + 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, "n", "u", "e"}, {2, "c", "b", "g"}, {3, "a", "t", "e"}, 
>   {4, "d", "i", "m"}, {5, "a", "h", "i"}, {6, "w", "z", "g"}}, 
>  {{"n", 1, "u", "e"}, {"c", 2, "b", "g"}, {"a", 3, "t", "e"}, 
>   {"d", 4, "i", "m"}, {"a", 5, "h", "i"}, {"w", 6, "z", "g"}}, 
>  {{"n", "u", 1, "e"}, {"c", "b", 2, "g"}, {"a", "t", 3, "e"}, 
>   {"d", "i", 4, "m"}, {"a", "h", 5, "i"}, {"w", "z", 6, "g"}}, 
>  {{"n", "u", "e", 1}, {"c", "b", "g", 2}, {"a", "t", "e", 3}, 
>   {"d", "i", "m", 4}, {"a", "h", "i", 5}, {"w", "z", "g", 6}}}
> ```