# Rearranging the columns of a matrix

Tags: matrix

How do I rearrange the columns of a matrix? I really have o idea how to do this. Thankfs for any suggestions!

Comment: What kind of rearrangement did you have in mind? In any event, you could work with the matrix's `Transpose[]` if need be.

Comment: THanks! I was thinking of something like choosing columns 4,5,7,8,11 in a matrix with more than 11 columns and putting them at the beginning of the matrix.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question to begin with; but, look up `Extract[]` and `Delete[]`. Or, multiply your matrix with an appropriately permuted identity matrix.

Comment: In general: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/5478

Comment: With respect to what you want to do, this is already answered in the question Kuba is referring to. See the "swap columns" part

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

E.g. to exchange row 2 and 3 while also exchanging column 1 and 2 in a 3x3 matrix,

```
rowOrd = {1,3,2};
colOrd = {2,1,3};
mat[[rowOrd, colOrd]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code could help you:

```
ord={1,3,5,9,11}
Extract[mat,ord]~Join~Delete[mat,ord]
```