# Efficiently exchange elements between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists with equal length, and I want to exchange the elements on every even positions. For example,

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

will return

```
{{1, 7, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 2, 8, 4, 10}}
```

It has to be able to deal with length of both even and odd; and in the real case the list is very long. I am not satisfied with naive approaches with indexing and partitioning because they are slow. Is there any fast approaches?

Comment: Closely related: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
list[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]] = Reverse @ list[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]]; 
list
```

> ```
> {{1, 7, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 2, 8, 4, 10}}
> ```

or `list[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 2 ;; ;; 2]]`.

ps. keep in mind that this changes `list`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is the fastest

Comment: I modified your code to use the backward-compatible form.  I also find this more readable as one can get lost in all the semicolons.  I hope you do not mind.

Comment: You could also eliminate `Reverse` with: `list[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]] = list[[{2, 1}, 2 ;; ;; 2]];`, or perhaps more explicitly `list[[{1, 2}, 2 ;; ;; 2]] = list[[{2, 1}, 2 ;; ;; 2]];`

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = Module[{l2 = Transpose@#}, l2 = Transpose[MapAt[Reverse, l2, {2 ;; ;; 2}]]] &;

f1@{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

> {{1, 7, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 2, 8, 4, 10}}

Or

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Module[{l2 = #}, 
    l2[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]] = Reverse /@ Transpose[l2[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]]]; l2] &;

f2@{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

> {{1, 7, 3, 2, 5}, {6, 9, 8, 4, 10}}

Comment: I knew spanning specification worked with `Take` (was designed for?), but it obviously works with `MapAt` as well. But a span of elements is generally not equivalent to a list of positions, right?

Answer (score 4):

I think `Reverse` is better suited for long lists. When the lists that need be reversed have length 2, I would do this:

```
L = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
Transpose[MapAt[#[[{2, 1}]] &, Transpose[L], 2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

Comment: I knew spanning specification worked with `Take` (was designed for?), but it obviously works with `MapAt` as well. But a span of elements is generally not equivalent to a list of positions, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
Module[{i = 1},
  Transpose@MapThread[If[EvenQ[i++], Reverse@{##}, {##}] &, lst]
 ]
(* {{1, 7, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 2, 8, 4, 10}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};

Riffle @@ ReverseSortBy[Length] @
  Map[Lookup[#], GroupBy[OddQ] /@ list] & /@ {True, False}
```

{{1, 7, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 2, 8, 4, 10}}

Answer (score 0):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, b, c}, 
  Style[#, Blue] & /@ {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, d, e, f}}
```

[image]

```
(* select even positions *)

pos = Position[list, _, {2}, Heads -> False] // Select[EvenQ@*Last];

(* rotate according to the number of columns/2 floored to an integer *)

SubsetMap[
 RotateLeft[#, Floor[(First@Dimensions@Last@list)/2]] &, list, pos]
```

[image]