# Can't define average for my matrix

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, warning-messages

I have a list defined as `MarsDisk` which, in `MatrixForm`, has 17 rows and 3 columns, which hold information about a photon energy level, photon flux, and uncertainty in the flux.  I'm interested in taking the average of the energy levels and executed the following:

```
Average[MarsDisk[[i, 2]]]
```

and I received this error message:

> Part::partw: Part 18 of {{0.8725,0.5,0.5},{0.817,0.4,0.4},[continues
>   with the rest of my data points]} does not exist. >>

I don't get why this doesn't work because I never asked for the 18th element.

Then, I tried to create a For loop instead:

```
ψ = Array[c, {17, 2}];

For [i = 1, i <= 17, i++,

 ψ[[i, 1]] = Avg[MarsDisk[[i, 1]]];

 ψ[[i, 2]] = Avg[MarsDisk[[i, 2]]]]
```

which gave no error message but when I executed `ψ` it printed all elements as `{Avg[0.8725], Avg[0.5]}`, etc.  So neither way worked.

Can anyone show me a way to successfully quantify the averages for each column of information in my matrix?

Comment: I should add that I changed "Avg" to "Average" and the same exact issue came up

Comment: why don't you use 'All' instead of defining a loop? can you give an example of your matrix? for example use Average[a[[All,2]]]

Comment: I'm an amateur with this stuff and didn't know about using All.  I tried Average[MarsDisk[[All,2]]] and it worked out just fine!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped :) Also if you use the 'Mean' function it gives the average of each column of your matrix.

Comment: If you ran the `For` loop, then at the end of that evaluation `i` will be 18. This could explain the error message from `Part` you are seeing.

Comment: `Average` is not a built-in function. Have you looked at [Mean](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html)

Comment: More on matrices : [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

Answer (score 2):

```
 matrix = Table[RandomReal[], {n, 1, 17}, {i, 1, 3}]

 Mean[matrix[[All, 2]]]
```

and i get the result