# Writing a program to swap rows and columns

Tags: matrix, programming

I would like to swap rows with other rows or columns. Not for any particular size but for any size. I saw this detailed [Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns) but it didn't answer my query.

I want to swap multiple rows or columns for a $N\times N$ (variable) matrix. I tried with lots of `While` and `If` loops but with no success.

How to write a program in *Mathematica* for this?

As an example, I am interested in swapping rows for an even $N$ as follows:

- row 1 and $N$ are fixed,
- row 2 becomes row 3, row 3 becomes row 2,
- row 4 becomes row 5, row 5 becomes row 4,
- and so on...

In Fortran this is trivial but how to implement this in *Mathematica*?

```
program swap // Fortran version
integer Ndim,i
Ndim=40
do, i=1:Ndim
    do, j=1:Ndim
      If(i<j)then
        matrix(i,j)=i+j
      endif
    enddo
enddo

Ndim=20
 do i=1,Ndim
    if (mod(j,2)==0 .and. j < Ndim) then
       matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j+1)
    elseif(mod(j,2)!=0 .and. j<Ndim)then  // !=  not equal to
       matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j-1)
    endif
 end do
end program
```

Any starting point will be very valuable. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the answers on the question you linked do not satisfy your need?

Comment: Because it is for a specific case(like row 1 with 3 or otherwise). But if I have to swap many rows or columns, I can't write all of them explicitly. But inside a loop in a program.

Comment: @lavkush You can always generate a list of indices that you want to swap. A loop is never needed for this purpose.

Comment: @m_goldberg It isn't, in the question explained it clearly. Because any sort of swapping not only some particular type but also size can be any, so choice of indices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Swapping rows**

*Code.*

```
swapRows[matrix_?SquareMatrixQ] /; EvenQ[Length[matrix]] := 
     Module[{mat = matrix, r = Range[2, Length[matrix] - 1]}, 
         mat[[r]] = mat[[Flatten[Reverse /@ Partition[r, 2]]]];
         mat
     ];
```

*Usage.*

```
mat = Partition[Range[36], 6];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
swapRows[mat] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Swapping columns**

*Code.*

```
swapColumns[matrix_?SquareMatrixQ] /; EvenQ[Length[matrix]] := 
     Module[{mat = matrix, r = Range[2, Length[matrix] - 1]}, 
         mat[[All, r]] = mat[[All, Flatten[Reverse /@ Partition[r, 2]]]];
         mat
     ];
```

*Usage.*

```
swapColumns[mat]
```

[image]

**Comments**

For other swappings, you will need to generate the list of rows or columns you want to swap in the appropriate way, as mentioned by C.E. in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126990/swapping-rows-and-columns-program/127008#comment343505_126990).

Answer (score 4):

The `Do` loop comes to mind:

```
swapR[mat_] := Block[{mat1},
  mat1 = ConstantArray[0, Length@mat];
  Do[
   mat1[[1]] = mat[[1]];
   mat1[[Length@mat]] = mat[[Length@mat]];
   mat1[[{i, i + 1}]] = mat[[{i + 1, i}]];,
   {i, 2, Length@mat - 2, 2}
   ];
  mat1
  ]

swapC[mat_] := Block[{mat1, matT = Transpose@mat},
  mat1 = ConstantArray[0, Length@mat];
  Do[
   mat1[[1]] = matT[[1]];
   mat1[[Length@matT]] = matT[[Length@matT]];
   mat1[[{i, i + 1}]] = matT[[{i + 1, i}]];,
   {i, 2, Length@matT - 2, 2}
   ];
  Transpose@mat1
  ]
```

The idea of `swapR` is to define a new matrix, `mat1`, with its first and last rows the same as the input matrix `mat`. The other rows are interchanged pairwise with the line `mat1[[{i, i + 1}]] = mat[[{i + 1, i}]]` - this swaps row `i` and `i+1`. An (un-tested in the code) assumptions is that there is an even number of rows, so it has to go through `i = 2, 4, ...`, hence the iterator of the `Do` loop.

Swapping columns is equivalent to swapping rows of a transposed matrix and transposing the result, hence the `Transpose` in inserted in the `swapC` code.

The `RepeatedTiming`s are practically the same as with [Xavier's approach.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127008/22013)

---

**EDIT:** The above codes answer explicitly the OP. A more flexible approach will be as follows.

To swap any two rows `i` and `j` of a general $m\times n$ matrix:

```
swapRij[mat_, {i_, j_}] := Block[{mat1 = mat},
  mat1[[{i, j}]] = mat[[{j, i}]];
  mat1
  ]
```

Usage: `swapRij[mat, {1, 2}]` swaps the first and second rows of `mat`. Note the second argument is a list.

Similarly, to swap any two columns `i` and `j`:

```
swapCij[mat_, {i_, j_}] := Block[{matT = Transpose@mat},
  matT[[{i, j}]] = matT[[{j, i}]];
  Transpose@matT
  ]
```

The functions `swapRij` and `swapCij` can be used on a set of pairs of rows/columns to be swapped. Let's take e.g. `mat = Partition[Range[36], 6]` and do

```
Fold[swapRij[#1, #2] &, mat, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

swaps the 1st and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, and 5th and 6th rows:

[image]

Similarly for `Fold`ing `swapCij`.

Comment: Swapping using Do loop

Comment: Can you little bit explain it. It will be of great help. Because I would like to  change only the rows (1->2, 2-> 1) and 3->4, 4->3 but last two rows not changing. Would like to learn the code. So that I can learn all the possibilities

Comment: Explanation helped, and I was able to do my own swapping. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: `mat = V1;
swapR[mat_] := Block[{mat1}, mat1 = ConstantArray[0, Length@mat];
  Do[mat1[[1]] = mat[[1]];
   mat1[[Length@mat]] = mat[[Length@mat]];
   mat1[[{i, i + 1}]] = mat[[{i + 1, i}]];, {i, 2, Length@mat - 2, 2}];
  mat1]
MatrixForm[mat1]`.  But no display of `mat1. V1` is properly defined.

Comment: ??? `mat1` is local, as indicated by the first argument of [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html); `swapR[V1]` is the output. Read [how to define and work with functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: Thanks alot. Ok I see now. I even don't know the output. I saw that mat1 before this end bracket ']' , so thought value is returned in mat1.