# Combine three lists in one with each other

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a question about combining lists, I really tried it, but that's so hard for me. I'm a newbie.

I have this kind of a list:

```
a={{{2,3},{1,2},{3,5}},{{1,9},{1,5},{1,7}},{{10,10},{10,10},{20,20}}}
```

I need this kind of result:

```
res={{{2,3},{1,2},{3,5},{10,10},{20}},{{1,9},{1,5},{1,7},{10,10},{20}}}
```

My list can have 1000 of elements...

I would be thankful for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? For example, which of the input's 10s end up where in the desired output? Why should the `{10,10},{20}` in the output (twice) be grouped like that?

Comment: These are 3 lists, which i already combine:

a1= {{2,3},{1,2},{3,5}},{{1,9},{1,5},{1,7}}
a2={{10,10},{10,10}}
a3={{20,20}}

Comment: What should happen if the 'third list' were `{{10,11},{12,13},{20,21}}` rather than `{{10,10},{10,10},{20,20}}`?

Comment: @MudyFa But your `a1` is not a list (missing `{}`s?), and your question does not involve `a2` and `a3` but rather `a2~Join~a3`... Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @jjc385 this doesnt matter... its only importan to combine them in the right direction

Comment: yes im sorry, u have to put on more {} belong all of them!

Comment: I'm asking you to clarify what the output should be if the 'third list' were `{{10,11},{12,13},{20,21}}` rather than `{{10,10},{10,10},{20,20}}`.  As you've described it, it's unclear what should happen.  If you're not interested in that case, then how about `{{10,10},{15,15},{20,20}}`?  It's just not clear enough from the question (at least to me) what should happen in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I assume some typos in your presentation, this seems to be another question about [how to append columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns).

```
a1 = {{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}}};
a2 = {{10, 10}, {10, 10}};
a3 = {{20}, {20}};
Fold[MapThread[Append, {#1, #2}] &, {a1, a2, a3}] (* appends all*)
% // MatrixForm  (* display nicely *)
```

Comment: Dont work, theres one coma mistake

Comment: @MudyFa Please copy the entire code.  It runs fine and produces your desired output.  Note that my `a3` is a correction of what you wrote: you said there were missing braces, so I added the braces needed for the format to make sense.

Comment: No i Mean, there is a mistake in Fold, just try it!!

Comment: @MudyFa You must have copied it wrong.  It works as it should.  If you are copying and pasting, that will sometimes lose end-of-lines.  But the code is good.

Comment: oh yes, it works, but there is something between, } and ] in the End of the Fold line something like this "^"

Comment: @MudyFa Odd, I see nothing of the sort, and I certainly pasted nothing of the sort.  Do you actually see this in your browser? What browser are you using?

Comment: version 9.0... hm i dont know

Comment: but what is , when i have a={{1,2},{2,1}} and b ={{1,3},{4,1}}

my result with MapThread[Append[#1,#2]&,{a,b}] is :

{{1,2,{1,3}},{2,1,{4,1}}} ?? i need :

{{{1,2},{1,3}},{{2,1},{4,1}}} ... i dont get this... the position is right but but the clamp not... can u help again please?

Comment: @MudyFa That is a very different question, because now `a` and `b` are matrices whereas your `a1` was a list of matrices.  I would write your new problem as `Transpose[{a, b}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}}};
b = {{10, 10}, {10, 10}};
c = {{20}, {20}};
```

Another possibility

```
MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, {#3}] &, {a, b, c}]
```

{{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}, {10, 10}, {20}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1,
7}, {10, 10}, {20}}}

Answer (score 1):

I have changed a few entries to visually differentiate where the items are landing after various operations. Matrix dimensions, however, remain the same as those from the accepted answer.

```
a = {{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}}};
b = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}};
c = {{25}, {35}};

g1 = MapThread[Join@## &, {a, List /@ b, List /@ c}];

g2 = MapThread[Join, {a, List /@ b, List /@ c}];

g3 = MapThread[Catenate@{##} &, {a, List /@ b, List /@ c}];

g1 == g2 == g3
```

(* True *)

---

*Result:*

```
MatrixForm /@ {a, b, c, g1}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}}};
b = {{10, 10}, {10, 10}};
c = {{20}, {20}};
```

Using `Thread` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReplaceAll[m_?MatrixQ :> Splice@m][Thread[{a, b, c}]]

(*{{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}, {10, 10}, {20}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}, {10, 10}, {20}}}*)
```