# Join the matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a question about joining matrices. Lets say

```
nnmat[[1, 1]] = ({{1, 3},{3, 5}});
nnmat[[1, 2]] = ({{2, 6},{4, 5}});
nnmat[[1, 3]] = ({{3, 2},{8, 7}});

Join[nnmat[[1, 1]], nnmat[[1, 2]], nnmat[[1, 3]], 2]
```

The above code gives me what I want but I want to extend this code into a more general situation when I have nnmat matrix more than three.

If I give an example, it will be more clear. Lets say I have a code which is wrong but it is given by using the parameter, j.

```
Join[{nnmat[[1,j]],{j,3}},2]
```

How could I rearrange the above code consisting parameter j, to give the same solution for the first example mentioned at the beginning.

Best Regards,

Comment: Have a look at `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: You might also be interested in the techniques highlighted here: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

Comment: `Flatten /@ Transpose[nnmat[1]]]` or `Flatten /@ Transpose[nnmat[1,;;3]]]`

Comment: BTW the syntax for what you are tying to do with the iterator `j` would be like : `Join[Sequence @@ Table[nnmat[[1, j]], {j, 3}], 2]`

Comment: Thank you @george2079 I have solved my problem