# Adding a zero vector into an inside column or row of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Let's say I have a 3x3 matrix and I want to insert zero vector into all second row and all second column of the matrix. At the end, the previous second row shifted to third row and the previous second column shifted to third column. The new second row and column terms will all be zero. How could I solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data you have tried yourself. Use **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/10397) and therefore  [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). Please [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis in what was NOT answered in the other question. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Answer (score 2):

```
(mat = Partition[Range[25], 5]) // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
>  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
>  16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
>  21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
mat2 = ArrayFlatten[ReplacePart[TakeList[mat,
                                         {1, 0, UpTo[∞]}, {1, 0, UpTo[∞]}],
                                {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}} -> 0]]
MatrixForm[mat2]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
>  11 & 0 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
>  16 & 0 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
>  21 & 0 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Coolwater but my mathematica v.9.0.1.0 and does not recognize TakeList, unfortunately.

Comment: maybe I could use Take instead of TakeList, however I could not understand what it means {1,0,UpTo[∞]}

Comment: `{row, col} = {3, 4};
mat = Insert[mat, 0 mat[[row]], row];
mat = Transpose@Insert[Transpose@mat, 0 mat[[All, col]], col];
mat // MatrixForm`