# Replacing a column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to replace a column of a matrix. The best I've been able to come up with is

```
a=RandomReal[9,{5,5}]
b=ConstantArray[0,5]
replacepos=4
Transpose[ReplacePart[Transpose[a], replacepos -> b]],
```

which does the trick, but looks awkward to me.

Comment: Did you search the site before posting? This has been asked a bunch of times...

Comment: There is the insert function I believe is useful for you.

Comment: `a.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, yes I did, but previous questions seemed to look for more complex things. Thanks

Comment: Related (not dupe): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
a[[All, replacepos]] = b
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, `Transpose` has to perform superfluous reorderings which are memory bound. This does the trick and should be fairly efficient:

```
c = Module[{buffer = a},
  buffer[[All, replacepos]] = b;
  buffer
  ]
```

Comment: It wd be nice to compare with [these suggestions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270083/19530) to use `ReplacePart` or `SubsetMap`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = RandomReal[9, {5, 5}]
(a[[#, 4]] = 0) & /@ Range@5
a
```