# How to replace the 6th column with another column?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following table:

```
tabb = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100], {i, 1, 10, 1}];
```

How to replace its kth column (say, the 52th column) by the column

`col=Table[{i},{i,1,10,1}]`?

Comment: `tabb[[All, 52]] = col`. Since Mathematica doesn't differentiate between column and row vectors, you might just want to have a plain list there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your data is just made up for an example, but just for reference, you can do this:

```
tabb = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {10, 100}]
```

I also assume that you don't intend to replace numbers with lists, so let's simplify your new column:

```
col = Range@10
```

Now we have a couple of options. If you want to mutate in place, you can use Set directly:

```
tabb2[[All, 52]] = col
```

If you want a new structure, one option is SubsetMap:

```
newtabb = SubsetMap[col &, tabb, {All, 52}]
```

Another is MapThread:

```
newtabb = MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, 52 -> #2] &, {tabb, col}]
```

Another is just ReplacePart with patterns:

```
newtabb = ReplacePart[tabb, {row_, 52} :> col[[row]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

To clearly see the results it is better to use symbolic arrays and vectors. And dimensions on the order of 100 are excessive in a minimal example.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(Format[#[i__]] := Subscript[#, Row[{i}]]) & /@ {a, b};

(tabb = Array[b, {5, 8}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
col = Array[Style[a[#], Red] &, Length@tabb];
```

As Syed indicated, to replace column `3`

```
tabb[[All, 3]] = col;

tabb // MatrixForm
```

[image]