# Reimplementing SubsetMap

Tags: list-manipulation

[SubsetMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) introduced in V12 seems like it could be useful for aggregate list/matrix operations, like the kind wanted in [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

If you wanted to reimplement this function (both to avoid the dependence on V12 and for learning), how would you go about doing so?

My first attempt was something like:

```
SubsetMap[f_, expr_, pos_] := 
 ReplacePart[expr, 
  Thread[Function[{u, v}, u -> v][pos, f[expr[[pos]]]]]]
```

Which works for the two examples with explicit indices on the wolfram docs, but fails with the list "slice" notation (e.g. `2;;5`) as well as multidimensional lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very quick-n-dirty (so expect it to break), works on the first four examples in the 12.0 documentation. I'll revisit to accommodate named range cases (`All`, `UpTo`, etc.) if/when time permits, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
subsetmap[f_, l_, r_] := 
 ReplacePart[l, Thread[r -> f[l[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ r]]];
subsetmap[f_, l_, r_Span] := 
 With[{t = Range @@ r}, ReplacePart[l, Thread[t -> f[l[[t]]]]]] ;
```

V12 examples:

```
SubsetMap[Reverse, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {2, 4}] == 
 subsetmap[Reverse, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {2, 4}]

SubsetMap[RotateLeft, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {2, 4, 5}] == 
 subsetmap[RotateLeft, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {2, 4, 5}]

SubsetMap[Accumulate, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, 2 ;; 5] == 
 subsetmap[Accumulate, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, 2 ;; 5]

SubsetMap[Reverse, 
  Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}], {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}] ==
 subsetmap[Reverse, 
  Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}], {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}]
```

> True
>
> True
>
> True
>
> True

This seems more robust, and allows spans and `{All,2}` flavors (named ranges). I use `MapAt` to tag, then process. Note that for single-dimension lists, the alternative element position format shown in the `SubsetMap` docs must be used, e.g., `{{1},{3},{5}}` for `{1,3,5}`. This seems to work on the examples I tried, but again, caveat lector.

```
subsetmap[f_, l_, r_] := Module[{h1, h2, t},
   h2 = MapAt[h1, l, r];
   t = Most /@ Position[h2, h1];
   ReplacePart[l, Thread[t -> f[l[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ t]]]];
```

Comment: Very nice! There's also the degenerate case of duplicate positions for which the MapAt tries to nest h1. `DeleteDuplicates` on `r` should take care of this without affecting anything else.