# Pure functions applied to a two dimensional list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming

Lets say I have a two dimensional list:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {aa, bb, cc}, {x, y, z}, {xx, yy, zz}};
```

and two pure functions:

```
f1 = Total[#]/Length[#] &;
f2 = Total[##]/Length[##] &;
```

I want to learn how to apply these functions over rows and columns of a list using `Map`, `MapThread`, `MapAt` and `Apply`. 
Here:

```
f1 /@ list
```

produces, as expected,

[image].

But, why `MapThread` does not work as it supposed to work in `MapThread[f1, list]`?

Similarly,
`f1 @@ list` works as expected but `f1 @@@ list` does not work, why?

`MapAt[f1, list, 2]` works fine but `MapAt[f1, list, {All, 2}]` does not work, why?

What is the most efficient way to apply these pure functions to columns of the list without Transpose? My goal is to learn how to apply pure functions column wise most efficiently. I would appreciate general answer.

Comment: Should be `MapThread[f1, {list}]`. `Length @@@ list` will shed also some light on the issue.

Comment: To apply to a column, for example `f1 /@ {list[[All, 2]]}` yields {1/4 (b + bb + y + yy)}

Comment: Both `MapThread[f1, list]` and `MapAt[f1, list, {All, 2}]` work as I expect them to. -- What did you expect?  [Somewhere in the world there are animations that show how some of these functions work.  I found out about the on this site.  I cannot find them now, though. They might be helpful, if someone can locate them.]

Comment: Perhaps try `MapThread[f, list]` and `MapAt[f, list, {All, 2}]` with an undefined function `f` to see where the arguments come from.

Comment: @ Michael, thank you for your feedback. MapThread[f, list]={f[a, aa, x, xx], f[b, bb, y, yy], f[c, cc, z, zz]} and MapThread[f, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]={f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]}. I would expect the function be applied to each column. I might be missing something here.

Comment: Note `f[a, aa, x, xx]` is `f` applied to the first column. I guess you wanted `f[{a, aa, x, xx}]`, that is, a column as a "vector" and not with its components threaded into the arguments. That's not how arrays are structured: the columns are not stored as lists or vectors. If you compose `f` with `List` you get what I guessed you wanted: `MapThread[f @* List, list]`. If you need to do a lot of column operations, consider transposing once and operating on that. In some cases it will be easier and faster. [Tip: Don't put a space between the @ and the user name, or the user won't be notified.]

Comment: @ Michael, thank you for your feedback. As a new user, I think there is some magic, somebody knows and I don't know. I guess I am wrong! I might have to define the pure function differently.

Comment: Here are the animations: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/ -- There's one for the `f @@ list` form of `Apply` but not `f @@@ list` form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at how `Map` and `MapThread` are applied to a two-dimensional list.

```
Map[f, list]
```

> {f[{a, b, c}], f[{aa, bb, cc}], f[{x, y, z}], f[{xx, yy, zz}]}

and `MapThread[f, list]`

> {f[a, aa, x, xx], f[b, bb, y, yy], f[c, cc, z, zz]}

```
Total[#]/Length[#] & /@ list
```

> {1/3 (a + b + c), 1/3 (aa + bb + cc), 1/3 (x + y + z), { 1/3 (xx + yy
>   + zz)}

Similarly,

`MapThread[Total[List[##]]/Length[List[##]] &, list]`

> {1/4 (a + aa + x + xx), 1/4 (b + bb + y + yy), 1/4 (c + cc + z + zz)}

```
Total[List[##]]/Length[List[##]] & @@ list
```

> {1/4 (a + aa + x + xx), 1/4 (b + bb + y + yy), 1/4 (c + cc + z + zz)}

An efficient way to apply a function over a column of a list would be

```
Total[##]/Length[##] &@list[[All, {1, 3}]]
```

> {1/4 (a + aa + x + xx), 1/4 (c + cc + z + zz)}

Comment: @ ramesh, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure that how the functions 
[`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), 
[`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html),
[`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) and 
[`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)
work are explained in the documentation and on site, at least in the course of answering some other question; nonetheless, I'll try to give an elementary explanation of how they work.  It seems to me that the emphasis of the OP on "pure functions" is a red herring.  There is no real difference in applying any `f` as a function to `list`, except for the values that the function computes.  And since `f2` is not used in the question at all, it seems probable that the OP is not asking about the difference between [`Slot[1]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) (`#`) and [`SlotSequence[1]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) (`##`).

Animated illustrations of some applications of these functions can be found at the following webpage (which I found in [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)):

- https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/

A difference between mathematical matrices and "matrices" in *Mathematica* is that in *Mathematica* they are expressions with a structure.  Unlike mathematics, the structure is not symmetric with respect to rows and columns (hence the highly popular [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)).  The functions in question operate on the structure of expressions.  Two important concepts in the structure of expressions are the notions of [Levels](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html) and [Parts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html).  Here are the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) and the levels of the OP's `list`:

```
FullForm@list
(*
  List[
   List[a,  b,  c ],
   List[aa, bb, cc],
   List[x,  y,  z ],
   List[xx, yy, zz]
   ]
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Map`, `MapThread`, and `Apply` all have a [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) specification argument; `MapAt` has a [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) specification argument.  When we try to work with the columns of a matrix through these functions, we tend not to get a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) (or vector) of elements to work with; we tend to get a [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) of elements to work with.

It's easy to get rows by using parts: `list[[2]]` yields the second row; `list[[{3, 1}]]` yields a list of rows, the third and first in that order.  It's easy to get a single column as a `List` by using parts: `list[[All, 1]]` yields the column vector `{a, aa, x, xx}`. However, to get many columns is less convenient (if we don't use [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)):

```
list[[All, {3, 2}]]               (* parts 3 and 2 of All rows *)
(*  {{c, b}, {cc, bb}, {z, y}, {zz, yy}}  *)

list[[All, {3, 2}]] // Transpose  (* list of columns 3 and 2 *)
(*  {{c, cc, z, zz}, {b, bb, y, yy}}  *)
```

Now let's go back to our functions.  For `Apply`, applying `f @@ list` replaces level 0 (a single `List`) with `f` and `f @@@ list` replaces level 1 (four `List` heads) with `f`:

```
f @@ list
(*
  f[
   {a,  b,  c },
   {aa, bb, cc},
   {x,  y,  z },
   {xx, yy, zz}
   ]
*)

f @@@ list
(*
  List[
   f[a,  b,  c ],
   f[aa, bb, cc],
   f[x,  y,  z ],
   f[xx, yy, zz]
 ]
*)
```

In this instance `MapThread` might be viewed as performing a sort of transposed `f @@@ list`:

```
MapThread[f, list]
(*
  List[
   f[a, aa, x, xx],
   f[b, bb, y, yy],
   f[c, cc, z, zz]
   ]
*)
```

[`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/MapThread.html) takes the parts of each list `list[[1]],..., list[[4]]` and uses the corresponding parts as a sequence of arguments to `f`:

```
      list[[1]]  list[[2]]  list[[3]]  list[[4]]
{ f[      a,        aa,        x,        xx     ],
  f[      b,        bb,        y,        yy     ],
  f[      c,        cc,        z,        zz     ]  }
```

As for `MapAt`, 
`MapAt[f, list, {2}]` operates on parts at level 1 (because the length of `{2}` is 1); likewise
`MapAt[f, list, {All, 2}]` operates on parts at level 2 (because the length of `{All, 2}` is 2).
In the first case, we get `f` of the second row, which is part `{2}` of `list`;
in the second case, we get `f` of the second part of all the rows, 
which are parts `{1, 2}`, `{2, 2}`, `{3, 2}`, and `{4, 2}`:

```
MapAt[f, list, {2}]
(*
  List[
      {a,  b,  c},
   f[ {aa, bb, cc} ],
      {x, y, z},
      {xx, yy, zz}
   ]
*)

MapAt[f, list, {All, 2}]
(*
  List[
   {a,  f[ b  ], c },
   {aa, f[ bb ], cc},
   {x,  f[ y  ], z },
   {xx, f[ yy ], zz}
 ] 
*)
```

Side note: As for the efficiency of the computation intended by the OP's `f1`, I don't think anything can arguably beat this:

```
Mean[list]
(*  {1/4 (a + aa + x + xx), 1/4 (b + bb + y + yy), 1/4 (c + cc + z + zz)}  *)
```

It's equivalent in speed to `Total[list]/Length[list]` on [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array), much faster on unpacked arrays, and much easier to understand.

Comment: @ Michael, I cannot imagine how thankful I am. I really appreciate it for your time.

Comment: @DLT You're welcome.

Comment: @DLT It just occurred to me that `MapAt[f, list, {2, All}]` is the corresponding row version of the column operation `MapAt[f, list, {All, 2}]`.  In that case, I think the symmetry of the code is reflected in the symmetry of the operations, which may be the sort of correspondence you were hoping to find in the other operations.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most efficient ways (for machine precision data in a packed array) would be

```
Total[list, {1}]/Length[list]
```

> {1/4 (a + aa + x + xx), 1/4 (b + bb + y + yy), 1/4 (c + cc + z + zz)}

What is special here is that `Total` has a two-argument version that allows you to choose the dimenension of a tensor to sum over.

Comment: @ Henrik, I am not sure how this is different from Total[list]/Length[list]. Any help on MapThread and @@@ for the pure function would be appreciated.