# Elegant operations on associations and datasets

Tags: matrix, dataset, associations

As a useful extension of this question:

[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

I would like to ask:

***What are  for you elegant, short, useful or frequently used functions to use with associations or datasets?***

I propose to distinguish between

1. Simple associations
2. Associations with named columns and rows
3. Associations with named columns
4. Datasets

Some examples for each of these four categories follow:

**1. Simple associations**

```
aset = <|"A" -> 10., "B" -> 20., "C" -> 30., "D" -> 40.|>;
```

MovingAverage was recently changed to also work with associations (undocumented):

```
MovingAverage[aset, 2]
```

<|"B" -> 15., "C" -> 25., "D" -> 35.|>

**2. Associations of associations**

```
mset =
  <|"10" -> <|"A" -> 10., "B" -> 20., "C" -> 30., "D" -> 40.|>,
   "20" -> <|"A" -> 50., "B" -> 60., "C" -> 70., "D" -> 80.|>,
   "30" -> <|"A" -> 90., "B" -> 100., "C" -> 110., "D" -> 120.|>,
   "40" -> <|"A" -> 130., "B" -> 140., "C" -> 150., "D" -> 160.|>,
   "50" -> <|"A" -> 170., "B" -> 180., "C" -> 190., "D" -> 200.|>|>;
```

Transpose

```
mset // Query[Transpose] // Dataset
```

[image]

Add column total

```
Query[<|#, "Total" -> Total[#]|> &] @ mset // Dataset
```

[image]

Extract

```
Query[{"10", "20"}, {"A", "B"}] @ mset // Dataset
```

[image]

**3. Associations with named columns**

JoinAcross

```
cset = Values @ mset;

join = {<|"A" -> 10., "E" -> "Red"|>, <|"A" -> 90., "E" -> "Blue"|>};

JoinAcross[cset, join, "A", "Left"] // SortBy["A"] // Dataset
```

[image]

**4. Dataset**

Display as BarChart

```
dset = Dataset[mset];

dset[BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &]
```

[image]