# How to modify a position on a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of points:

`data := {{10, 15}, {20, 45}, {30, 97}, {40, 162}, {50, 221}, {60, 249}, {70, 231}, {80, 166}, {90, 75}, {100, -5}}`

What I want to do is leave the first position of each bracket as is, but multiply the second by a number, let's say 2, so I get

`{{10, 30}, {20, 90}, {30, 194},...}`
and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: No need to say sorry, finding duplicate does need a bit experience :) .

Comment: IMO the best (and fastest?) way to to this is to use [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html). `data.{{1,0},{0,2}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{10, 15}, {20, 45}, {30, 97}, {40, 162}, {50, 221}, {60, 
   249}, {70, 231}, {80, 166}, {90, 75}, {100, -5}};

data /. {a_, b_} :> {a, 2 * b}
```

{{10, 30}, {20, 90}, {30, 194}, {40, 324}, {50, 442}, {60, 498}, {70,
462}, {80, 332}, {90, 150}, {100, -10}}

Also:

```
MapAt[2 # &, data, {All, 2}]
```

and

```
Query[All, {2 -> (2 # &)}] @ data
```

(* same result *)

If you want to modify `data` inline:

```
data[[All, 2]] *= 2;

data
```

{{10, 30}, {20, 90}, {30, 194}, {40, 324}, {50, 442}, {60, 498}, {70,
462}, {80, 332}, {90, 150}, {100, -10}}

Recommended link:

[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)