# Building matrices by attaching vectors (columns) and matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Having the need to attach a column to a matrix or to join matrices to make longer rows is an operation that I use very frequently and I find the `Join` function ideal for these cases.

```
m1 = {{10, 11, 12}, {21, 22, 23}};
m2 = {100, 101};

(* Join matrices to make longer rows: *)
Join[m1, m1, 2]
(* --> {{10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12}, {21, 22, 23, 21, 22, 23}} *)

(* Attach a column to a matrix *)
Join[m1, List /@ m2, 2]
(* --> {{10, 11, 12, 100}, {21, 22, 23, 101}} *)

(* Join two columns to make a matrix *)
Join[List /@ m2, List /@ m2, 2]
(* --> {{100, 100}, {101, 101}} *)
```

However, I wanted to define my own function that would simplify the notation needed to reach my goal:

```
columnAttach[a1_List, a2_List] := 
  Join[If[VectorQ[a1], List /@ a1, a1], 
  If[VectorQ[a2], List /@ a2, a2], 2]

columnAttach[m1, m1]
(* --> {{10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12}, {21, 22, 23, 21, 22, 23}} *)
columnAttach[m1, m2]
(* --> {{10, 11, 12, 100}, {21, 22, 23, 101}} *)
columnAttach[m2, m2]
(* --> {{100, 100}, {101, 101}} *)
```

This works as expected, but I would like to generalize it a bit. For instance, `Join` can take a list of vectors/matrices of any length:

```
Join[m1, m1, List /@ m2, List /@ m2, 2]
(* --> {{10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12, 100, 100},
  {21, 22, 23, 21, 22, 23, 101, 101}} *)
```

How can I adapt my `columnAttach` function to achieve the same flexibility?

Comment: Why not using `ArrayFlatten` ?

Comment: Related (possible dupe): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility:

```
columnAttach[ak__List] := Join[##, 2] & @@ Replace[{ak}, v_?VectorQ :> List /@ v, 1]

columnAttach[{{10, 11, 12}, {21, 22, 23}}, {100, 101}, {{10, 11, 12}, {21, 22, 23}},
             {100, 101}, {100, 101}]
   {{10, 11, 12, 100, 10, 11, 12, 100, 100},
    {21, 22, 23, 101, 21, 22, 23, 101, 101}}
```

---

Alternatively:

```
columnAttach[ak__List] := ArrayFlatten[{Replace[{ak}, v_?VectorQ :> List /@ v, 1]}]
```

Comment: ..or, as the Wizard reminds, you could use the replacement rule `v_?VectorQ :> Transpose[{v}]`.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be faster than J. M.'s functions in all cases on my system:

```
columnAttach2[ak__List] := 
  Replace[Unevaluated@Join[ak, 2], v_?VectorQ :> {v}\[Transpose], 1]
```

Timings, using J. M.'s `Join` function (which tested faster):

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

m1 = RandomInteger[999, {50, 100}];
m2 = RandomInteger[999, 50];

columnAttach[m1, m2, m2, m1, m2, m1] // timeAvg

columnAttach2[m1, m2, m2, m1, m2, m1] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00019968
>
> 0.0000141696

Comment: Correction: it is no faster but also no slower than J. M.'s code for non-packed arrays but apparently always faster with packed arrays.