# Elegant way to handle columns operations

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-review

Inspired by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns) from @sjdh and by my recurrent use of columns operations in database sets, I was looking for one way to make columns operations more symetric, so I can handle with matrix and lists in a more clean way when working with this kind of data.

For instance, I think it's not very practical to append a list data to a matrix using `Join[matA, {colA} // Transpose, 2]` or prepend using `Prepend[Transpose@matA, colA] // Transpose`. It's very clumsy, but we get used to it (I realized that teaching to a friend).

I created this function called `colAppend`, that I would like to share here, and ask for performance tuning, tips on code organization and maybe another combinations of row operations that I have missed.

Here are our test matrix and lists:

```
matA={{mA1,mA2},{mA3,mA4},{mA5,mA6}};
matB={{mB1,mB2},{mB3,mB4},{mB5,mB6}};
colA={cA1,cA2,cA3};
colB={cB1,cB2,cB3};
```

Now there are the function `colAppend` definitions. I separated it in 3 blocks:

**1- Basic Join Operations**

```
colAppend[mat1_,mat2_]/;(Length@Dimensions@mat1>1&&Length@Dimensions@mat2>1):=
    Join[mat1,mat2,2]

colAppend[mat1_,col1_,pos_:-1]/;(Length@Dimensions@mat1>1&&Length@Dimensions@col1==1):=
    Insert[mat1//Transpose, col1, pos]//Transpose

colAppend[col1_,col2_]/;(Length@Dimensions@col1==1&&Length@Dimensions@col2==1):=
    Transpose[{col1,col2}]

colAppend[col1_,mat1_,pos_:1]/;(Length@Dimensions@col1==1&&Length@Dimensions@mat1>1):=
    Insert[mat1//Transpose, col1, pos]//Transpose

colAppend[colA,matA]//MatrixForm
colAppend[colA,colB]//MatrixForm
colAppend[matA,matB]//MatrixForm
colAppend[matA,colA]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

**2- Deleting Columns**

Maybe it could be another function `colDelete`, so we could remove the `Null` parameter.

```
colAppend[mat1_,Null,pos_:-1]/;(Length@Dimensions@mat1>1):=
Module[{temp=mat1},
    temp[[All,pos]]=Sequence[];
    temp
]

colAppend[Null,mat1_,pos_:1]/;(Length@Dimensions@mat1>1):=
Module[{temp=mat1},
    temp[[All,pos]]=Sequence[];
    temp
]

colAppend[matA,Null]//MatrixForm
colAppend[Null,matA]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

**3- Join Multiple Elements**

Combine all the above function (with except Null one)

```
colAppend::badargs = "Incompatible Dimensions";
colAppend[args__]:=Module[{list=List[args]},
    If[\[Not]Equal@@(First@Dimensions@#&/@list),Return[Message[colAppend::badargs]]];
    Fold[colAppend,First@list,Rest@list]
]

MatrixForm@colAppend[matA,colA,matB,colB]
```

[image]

What another functionality I'm missing?

**What is the best way to create such function?**

**Update 1**

As VLC has posted in the comments. For part 3, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14509/2266) from @Mr.Wizard is the best option, not just in simplicity, but in performance too!

```
columnAttach2[ak__List]:=Replace[Unevaluated@Join[ak,2],v_?VectorQ:>{v}\[Transpose],1]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14494/685

Comment: @VLC Hi. Interesting link. Will study that. Tks

Answer (score 2):

After some time looking for how to handler that question, I get into this set of function, that I have added to my tool-bag. The first one (colAttach) is from @Mr.Wizard.

```
colAttach[ak__List]:=Replace[Unevaluated@Join[ak,2],v_?VectorQ:>{v}\[Transpose],1]

colInsert[mat1_?MatrixQ,col1_?VectorQ,pos_:-1]:=Insert[mat1//Transpose, col1, pos]//Transpose
colInsert[mat1_?MatrixQ,mat2_?MatrixQ,pos_:-1]:=Insert[mat1//Transpose, mat2, pos]//Transpose//Flatten[#,1]&/@#&

colDelete[mat1_?MatrixQ,pos_:-1]:=Module[{r},
    r=mat1;
    r[[All,pos]]=Sequence[];
    r
]

colPermute[mat_List?MatrixQ,permCicle_List]:=Module[{r=mat,permute},
    Scan[(r[[All,#]]=r[[All,Reverse@#]])&,If[VectorQ[permCicle],{permCicle},permCicle]];
    r
]
```

The use of the first 3 (colAttach, colInsert and colDelete) works just as stated in the question.

The last one (colPermute) use the structure.

```
matA = {{mA1, mA2, mA3}, {mA1, mA2, mA3}, {mA1, mA2, mA3}};
mrtColPermute[matA, {1, 2}] // MatrixForm
mrtColPermute[matA, {{1, 2}, {3, 1}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: permuted matrix]

Answer (score 1):

As already noted the column append part of this question is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14494/121).

`colDelete` is already implemented as `Drop`, though you could tweak the syntax if you desire:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

Drop[a, None, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 9}}
> ```

Insert was asked about on StackOverflow:
[How to insert a column into a matrix, the correct Mathematica way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7537401/618728)

The double `Transpose` was the best method found.