# A Faster way to combine two Lists of different structures into one of a different structure

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

I have the following two lists (each containing over 500,000 elements). Here is a sample:

```
lis1 = { {1.86582, 1.70162, 1.25256}, {1.82707, 1.29901, 1.10659}, 
  {1.76547, 1.21544, 1.09433}, {1.18306, 1.28322, 1.75524}, 
  {1.12555, 1.98011, 1.53359}, {1.10584, 1.12299, 1.88411}, 
  {1.83799, 1.5275, 1.76179}, {1.42352, 1.45163, 1.45318}, 
  {1.63669, 1.78145, 1.60307}, {1.61749, 1.44287, 1.57405} 
};
```

and

```
lis2 = {0.826095, 0.73286, 0.918137, 0.937434, 0.506525, 
        0.562795, 0.664915, 0.789321, 0.6559, 0.398447}
```

They both have equal `Length`s. I want to combine both Lists to obtain a new list that looks like this

```
{ {1.86582, 1.70162, 1.25256, 0.826095}, 
{1.82707, 1.29901, 1.10659, 0.73286}, 
{1.76547, 1.21544, 1.09433, 0.918137}, 
{1.18306, 1.28322, 1.75524, 0.937434}, 
{1.12555, 1.98011, 1.53359, 0.506525}, 
{1.10584,1.12299, 1.88411, 0.562795}, 
{1.83799, 1.5275, 1.76179, 0.664915}, 
{1.42352, 1.45163, 1.45318, 0.789321}, 
{1.63669, 1.78145,1.60307, 0.6559}, 
{1.61749, 1.44287, 1.57405, 0.398447} }
```

That is, each element of the combined list contains the corresponding elements of `lis1` and `lis2`, with the first three elements being from `lis1` and the fourth element from `lis2`.
Here is what I did to combine them in this fashion:

```
Transpose[{lis1, lis2}] //. {{a_, b_, c_}, d_} :> {a, b, c, d}
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this as my lists are huge ?

Comment: `Join[lis1, List /@ lis2, 2]`

Comment: `Flatten /@ Thread[{lis1, lis2}]` ... some benchmarking might be in order...

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19563/2266) can help you...

Comment: Just a quick note, as you are discussing structure, readability is _very_ important, so I re-organized your lists to emphasize their structure and make it more easily apparent what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks.

Comment: @Rojo Nice one, very fast. The bottleneck in your code is in `List /@ ...`. This version will be considerably faster still: `Join[lis1, Transpose[{lis2}], 2]`.

Comment: Also worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4270802/618728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also `Transpose` :

```
Transpose @ Append[ Transpose[lis1], lis2]
```

`Transpose` is a really fast approach, and you need to append only one list `lis2`. So this probably can be faster than `Rojo's` approach and :

```
Transpose @ Append[ Transpose[lis1], lis2] == Join[lis1, List /@ lis2, 2]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

**Edit**

Leonid Shifrin provided in the comments another neat approach :

```
Join[ large1, Transpose[{large2}], 2]
```

which appears to be even faster on one-core machines and sometimes on multi-core ones. Following his idea we can use this testing function :

```
test := ( large1 = RandomReal[{0, 2.}, {10^6, 3}];
          large2 = RandomReal[{0, 2.}, 10^6];
         { Do[ Join[ large1, List /@ large2, 2], {100}]// AbsoluteTiming //First,
           Do[ Transpose @ Append[ Transpose[large1], large2],
                {100} ] // AbsoluteTiming // First, 
           Do[ Join[ large1, Transpose[{large2}], 2], {100}]// AbsoluteTiming// First})
```

Here are some benchmarks :

0n Win 7 64 bit AMD Phenom II x6 2.8 GHz, V9_0 :

```
 test
```

> ```
> {10.413086, 8.477539, 5.245117}
> ```

while RunnyKine on his machine :

Win 8 64bit Intel Core i7-2600 3.4GHz 16GB RAM, V9.0, got

```
test
```

> ```
> {6.006038, 1.794012, 1.825212}
> ```

Mr.Wizard on v7.0, Win7-64, i5-2500K 8GB RAM:

```
test
```

> ```
> {6.2400087, 2.5000035, 2.2700032}
> ```

on one-core old Pentium(R) 3.0 GHz 1GB RAM, V9.0

```
 test
```

> ```
> {16.812500, 14.328125, 9.203125}
> ```

All the above benchmarks seem to suggest that `Transpose` remarkably accelerates on multi-core machines and then `Transpose @ Append[ Transpose[lis1], lis2]` might be faster than Leonid's solution.

Comment: This is fast. +1. It's even better as the List size grows.

Comment: Good one, +1. See my comment on @Rojo's code, where I suggest an improvement, which makes it about twice faster than yours.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, actually as the List gets bigger, his is actually faster (2x) at least on my computer.

Comment: @RunnyKine Did you see my comment? I suggested an improvement on Rojo's code, and it is that improved version that, at least on my machine, is about 4 times faster than the original one, and twice faster than Artes's version, for large lists. I tested for the length `10^5` and `10^6`. Heuristically, it seems that the reason my version is twice faster is that it has only one `Transpose` operation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, yes I saw your comment, I used the improved version you suggested. I tested it for 10^5 elements, looping over 1000 times and his is faster on my computer. This is weird.

Comment: @RunnyKine Weird indeed, as I get the opposite result (Win 7 64 bit,V9_0).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and RunnyKine, Thanks for upvotes. It's a pitty that the question was marked as a duplicate, but if you could be so kind, feel free to edit my answer adding some benchmarks. Unfortunately, at the moment I can't do any reliable tests with my computer at hand.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for  adding your benchmarks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks for adding the benchmarks, we were editing at the same time. On my computer the corresponding times are: {6.006038, 1.794012, 1.825212}.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks, it's interesting. Could you provide information on the system and the processor you are using when getting these timings ?  Do you get them for the same (Leonid's) code ?  Perhaps it migth be because of some default paralellization on your multi-core machine.

Comment: @Artes, yes I'm using Leonid's code. Win 8 64bit Intel Core i7-2600 3.4GHz 16GB RAM, V9.0

Comment: `{6.2400087, 2.5000035, 2.2700032}` here; v7, Win7-64

Comment: I think it's not single-core vs. multi-core, but rather that the multi-core machines have more memory bandwidth and by using `Transpose` instead of doing it at the top level one makes better use of this resource. Of course, if the memory manager is multithreaded, there might be benefits on multi-core machines for that reason.