# How do I delete items at the same position from every sub-list within a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

We have data in a list called `megadata` where `megadata[[1]]` for instance are the temperatures of each data point, `megadata[[2]]` are the pressures, etc. We are trying to selectively remove data points to see how it changes our fits but I have been unable to get `Delete` or `Drop` or anything else to work. I need something to let me remove the same position from every nested list within the list. So for instance if I wanted to delete positions 2 and 3 I need something to change `megadata = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}` into  `megadata = {{1, 4}, {5, 8}, {9, 12}.

Edit: I'm really new to Mathematica (learning ahead of the semester as part of undergraduate research) so I'm having trouble understanding some of the comments made. I used the Drop[#, {2, 3}] & /@ megadata idea and it worked quite nicely for removing adjacent points but my nested lists have a length of 12 and when I would try using it as Drop[#, {4, 7}] & /@ megadata, it seemed to remove all the points between 4 and 7 (so it would remove 4,5,6, and 7). Is there anyway to modify this format slightly to make it not remove that whole range of points and only remove 4 and 7?

Edit 2: I actually think I found the answer. Didn't see the link to the duplicate answer above. Sorry real new to all of this. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: `megadata[[All, {1, 4}]]`

Comment: This is closely related to [Manipulating a sublist based on position](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42455/manipulating-a-sublist-based-on-position) although there are even closer posts, you should find them.

Comment: If you want to remove points i order to test a fit then I'd suggest using `Cases` with some sort of condition applied to a pattern. But we'd need an example of your real data.

Comment: @artes Your +1 and accepted answer in the cited link is somehow but not "closely" related :)

Comment: @eldo Thanks for an upvote, however a remark is needed, there is some kind of relativity in the concept of distance, so I don't insist that it is universal. When it comes to this problem I have to ask why you don't use a simpler and nicer approach: `list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {a, d}`?

Comment: Also duplicate: [(17002)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17002), [(18923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18923)

Answer (score 2):

Both `Delete` and `Drop` should certainly work if used with `Map`.

```
data = Partition[Range[4 4], 4]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
> ```

```
Drop[#, {2, 3}] & /@ data
Delete[#, {{2}, {3}}] & /@ data
```

Both return

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {5, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 16}}
> ```

But as eldo points out, `Map` can be avoided.

```
data[[All, {1, 4}]]
```

also works. Notice in this last case, you specify the columns you want to keep, rather than the ones you want to drop.

Answer (score 1):

```
data={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}

Part[#, {1, -1}] & /@ data
```

> {{1, 4}, {5, 8}, {9, 12}}

```
Cases[data, {a_, __, b_} :> {a, b}]
```

and many more possibilities

Comment: you don't need to use `Map`. see my comment above

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: `data[[All,{1,-1}]]` but my other comment was more like `DeleteCases[data, {a_/;some condition, __, b_/;maybe condition here too}]` etc because he wants to remove points from a fit