# Difference between two Listplots

Tags: plotting

this is a simple question, and excuse me if it's already been answered; I searched around and couldn't find anything.

I have two listplots, both along the same number of x data points, but with different y values. I want to find the difference between the two y values, while keeping the x values the same. I tried just subtracting the two, but that leaves all the x values as equal to 0, which is undesirable, of course.

Comment: Take a look at `Transpose`, `Part` etc.

Comment: This snippet is one way to get what you want: `Transpose[{list1[[All, 1]], (list1 - list2)[[All, 2]]}]`. Take @Kuba's advice though, and look these operations up in the docs. Also interesting: [Elegant way to handle columns operations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18923/27951); [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/27951).

Comment: You can do `MapThread[#1-{0,Last@#2}&,{list1,list2}]` if you want something short. Or `list1 - ({0, 1}*# & /@ list2)`.

Comment: Ugh, I wish there was a better way to do this.  I am often trying to do something like this,  and end up using the `Transpose` listed by MarcoB, but every time I write it it just feels clunky to me.

Answer (score 2):

ok, you have two lists,

```
list1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 11}, {6, 13}, {7, 17}}
list2 = {{1, 3.87}, {2, 3.53}, {3, 3.40}, {4, 3.33}, {5, 3.25}, {6, 4.25}, {7, 5.24}}
```

and  you know how to plot them,

```
ListPlot[{list1, list2}]
```

[image]

[List Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html) giving massive and solid knowledge about *List*

```
list1[[All, 2]] - list2[[All, 2]]
```

> {-1.87, -0.53, 1.6, 3.67, 7.75, 8.75, 11.76}

```
ListPlot[list1[[All, 2]] - list2[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]

or, as proposed by @MarcoB

```
Transpose[{list1[[All, 1]], (list1 - list2)[[All, 2]]}]
```

> {{1, -1.87}, {2, -0.53}, {3, 1.6}, {4, 3.67}, {5, 7.75}, {6, 
>     8.75}, {7, 11.76}}

well, which generates us a new *List*.

Have Fun!

Answer (score 2):

Turn the data into time series, and do the arithmetic with them:

```
ts1 = TimeSeries[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 11}, 
                  {6, 13}, {7, 17}}];
ts2 = TimeSeries[{{1, 3.87}, {2, 3.53}, {3, 3.40}, {4, 3.33}, 
                  {5, 3.25}, {6, 4.25}, {7, 5.24}}];

Normal[ts1 - ts2]
```

> {{1, -1.87}, {2, -0.53}, {3, 1.6}, {4, 3.67}, {5, 7.75}, 
>         {6, 8.75}, {7, 11.76}}

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
ListPlot@Thread[{Flatten[{#1[[1]][[All, 1]] - #1[[2]][[All,1]]}],
#1[[1]][[All, 2]]}] &@{{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{1,1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}}
```