# Efficient method for Inserting arrays into arrays

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, faq

This is strongly related to the following Questions:

- [Looking for a way to insert multiple elements into multiple positions simultaneously in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30647/looking-for-a-way-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-multiple-positions-simultaneo)
- [Building matrices by attaching vectors (columns) and matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14494/building-matrices-by-attaching-vectors-columns-and-matrices)
- [What is the most efficient way to add rows and columns to a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-matrix)

I am looking for an efficient method to insert an array into an array. Let’s assume that both arrays have similar number of rows. Let’s further assume insertion is by column.

```
a = {{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2}, {a3, b3, c3, d3, e3}}; (*example may be larger*)
b = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}}; (*example may be larger*)
```

**Q1:**   What is the fastest method to insert **b** into **a** at a position *p*. Let’s assume that both arrays have similar number of rows. Let’s further assume insertion is by column.

My current method is as follows:

```
insertarray[a_, b_, pos_] :=
FlattenAt[
Transpose@Insert[Transpose@a, b[[##]], pos ] & [Range[Length@a]], 
Table[{i, pos}, {i, 1, Length@a}]];
```

which allows me to do

[image: insert array]

**Q2**: Some times I have to intersperse columns of **b** into **a** at multiple positions. How do I best extend **insertarray** so that:

```
insertarray[a,b,{1,2,5}]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: "Insertion" is not very well defined as shown unless a and b both have the same length. If this is the case, you should tell everyone that constraint.

Comment: @VF1 a and b both have the same number of column elements... but yes, it would be better to be explicit whether the insertion is by row or column (esp. with square matrices)

Comment: Edited for clarity. Added constraint insertion is by column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Q1

```
Join[a[[;; , ;; 1]], b, a[[;; , 2 ;;]], 2]
```

> [image]

One may want to create function

```
insCol[a_, b_, n_] := Join[a[[;; , ;; n - 1]], b, a[[;; , n ;;]], 2]

insRow[a_, b_, n_] := Join[a[[;; n - 1]], b, a[[n ;;]]]
```

Comment: This one's really fast (and the cleanest solution, too) - good job!

Comment: @VF1 Great you like it, thanks ;)

Comment: I really like this solution. its very clean and does the job well…

Comment: @Kuba , how can this function be used to add the array/ matrix b after EACH array of the original matrix a?

Comment: @Titus do you mean after each column of `a`?

Comment: @Kuba almost. I am looking for a way to input rows of 0 in a matrix, such as in the following example `ted = Table[Range[3], {3}];
stan2 = ConstantArray[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 3];
Partition[Flatten[Thread[{stan2, ted}]], 3]` Having the example for columns as well would help

Answer (score 2):

After a few attempts, the following gives a noticeable if unremarkable improvement over `insertarray`:

```
columnInsert[a_, b_, pos_] := 
  MapThread[Join[#1[[;; pos - 1]], #2, #1[[pos ;;]]] &, {a, b}];
```

Your second functionality doensn't actually need anything fancy, just some swaps afterwards:

```
SetAttributes[columnInsert`swap, HoldFirst];
columnInsert`swap[mat_, first_, list_] :=
 Module[{i = first}, 
  Scan[columnInsert`tmp = mat[[All, i]]; 
     mat[[All, i++]] = mat[[All, #]]; 
     mat[[All, #]] = columnInsert`tmp; &, list]; mat]
columnInsert[a_, b_, pos_List] := 
 Module[{res = columnInsert[a, b, First@pos]},
  columnInsert`swap[res, First@pos, pos]; res]
```

Comment: VF1. Thanks. I tried the MapThread method as well… I was almost going to accept this as the solution…

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test if this is faster (probably not), but I find it easier to read:

```
Block[{x, T = Transpose}, Insert[T@a, x, 2] /. x -> Sequence @@ T@b // T]
```

or alternately:

```
MapThread[Flatten[## ~Insert~ 2] &, {a, b}]
```

Both give the following:

[image]

Comment: You beat me to the second one. I didn't find it much faster, though. One thing that sped it up slightly is `Flatten[..., 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Inserting `b` at column `p` :-

```
a = {{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2}, {a3, b3, c3, d3, e3}};
b = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};

p = 4;

c = ReleaseHold@MapThread[Insert, {a, Hold[Sequence @@ #] & /@ b, Table[p, {Length@a}]}];

MatrixForm[c]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried something along these lines, but I found the additional `ReleaseHold` was too expensive - the whole expression needed to be traversed again for `Hold`s.

Comment: @VF1 - I wondered. It will be interesting to see the timings.