# How to join two one dimension lists as columns in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to take a one dimensional list, e.g., `list1={1,2,3}` and add a second column, e.g., `list2={a,b,c}` to get `list3={{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}}`.

I know that one can add a column to a matrix using Transpose and Join, but this doesn't seem to work for a simple list.

Comment: `list1 = {1, 2, 3};
list2 = {a, b, c};
{list1, list2} // Transpose` or `Thread`

Comment: `columnAttach[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14499)

Comment: See [`List Manipulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Answer (score 4):

<s>Let's try to do 10 ways.</s>

Courtesy of @cvgmt in the comments under the OP

```
{list1, list2} // Transpose
{list1, list2} // Thread
```

My original answer

```
Inner[List, list1, list2, List]
ArrayReduce[Dot, {list1, list2}, 1]
ArrayReshape[Riffle[list1, list2], {Length@list1, 2}]
MapThread[List, {list1, list2}]
Table[{list1[[i]], list2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@list1}]
```

Another great recommendation by @cvgmt as a comment under this answer

```
Outer[List, list1, list2] // Diagonal
```

@Nasser's suggested solution

```
MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {list1, list2}]
```

@Michael E2 used **[J. M.'s function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14494/building-matrices-by-attaching-vectors-columns-and-matrices/14499#14499)** in the following way

```
columnAttach[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]
```

All of the above give

> [image: res]

Comment: Or `Outer[List, list1, list2] // Diagonal`

Comment: I do not know if this counts different that one already given using MapThread. `MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {list1, list2}]`

Comment: @cvgmt that's a very nice suggestion. Why don't you make it an answer with the other two ways in the comment under the OP?

Comment: @Nasser I guess it should be sufficiently different for an alternative answer :-)

Comment: may be you could collect these into your answer and see if we got 10 or not. I think we have 10 different ones already scattered in comments and in your answer..

Comment: @Nasser done :-)

Comment: Not meaning to offend anyone, but with regard to Outer I don’t think we should promote using $O(n^2)$ operations for $O(n)$ tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, haven't seen this one yet:

```
Flatten[{list1, list2}, {2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I keep forgetting about this use of `Flatten`

Answer (score 2):

Here we go again with another way:

```
Values@GroupBy[Join @@ (PositionIndex[#] & /@ {list1, list2}), Key, Keys]

(*{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}*)
```

Also:

```
Partition[Riffle[list1, list2], {Length@{list1, list2}}]
```

Comment: 12 and counting! Very nice :-)