# Getting good-looking matrix form output from a matrix having both scalars and matrices as elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, output-formatting

I have a nested matrix `n`:

```
n = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
a = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 1, 0, sh}}
b = {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}

c = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}
d = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 1, 0, sh}}
```

With thanks to Nasser [add column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537401/how-to-insert-a-column-into-a-matrix-the-correct-mathematica-way) and Andy and Mike [most efficient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-matrix) for their questions and answers, we can add a vector `m = {rr, kk}` to this nested matrix as a column, for example:

```
pp = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[n], Flatten@m, 1]]
or
pp=Join[List /@ m, n, 2] // MatrixForm
```

Finally, after running the above lines we have `pp` as:

```
{{rr, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 1, 0, sh}},       
      {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}, 
 {kk, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1,0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}, 
      {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 1, 0,sh}}}}
```

and `pp/MatrixForm` as:
[image]

The result is correct but I wanted to obtain an obvious and clarified figure of `pp/MatrixForm` same as :

[image]

Are there any possibility for obtaining the last form instead of the first form for `pp/MatrixForm`.

Comment: `MatrixForm[MapAt[MatrixForm, #, {2 ;;}] & /@ pp]`?

Comment: Thank you so much, It was wonderful. I am so sorry can I ask a question,is the role of {2;;} for existence of 2 rows? for example if I had pp 3 rows I must write {3;;}?

Comment: I posted a cleaner version using `MapAt` which should work regardless of the numbers of rows/columns.

Comment: Yes I saw, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pp = {{rr, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 1, 0, sh}},       
          {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}, 
     {kk, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1,0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}, 
          {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 1, 0,sh}}}}; 

MapAt[MatrixForm, pp, {{All, All}, {}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Inasmuch as, I need so much to do work with matrices, are there any comprehensive documents for the matrices category and some related syntax, like _Map_, _Mapat_, _MapThread_ and so on? because the help of _Mathematica_ is not enough for being expert in this territory.

Comment: @mostafa, I find the tutorials in [Virtual Book](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) extremely useful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define your matrix as

```
p = {{rr, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 1, 0, sh}},       
  {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}, 
  {kk, {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1,0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}, 
  {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 1, 0,sh}}}};
```

You could do the `MatrixForm` on the outermost and the inner levels:

```
#[Map[#,p,{2}]]&@MatrixForm
```

[image: MATRIX]

An alternative form would be

```
MatrixForm//#[Map[#,p,{2}]]&
```