# references in a nested matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a nested matrix `n`:

```
n = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
a = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}
b = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 0, 1, sh}}

c = {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 1, th}, {0, 0, 0, sh}}
d = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}
```

With thanks to Kuba and Mr.Wizard '[comparison-operation-for-nested-matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51541/comparison-operation-for-nested-matrices)' I could get a *combined* nested matrix: *ncombined* (on which a comparison operation was applied)

```
ncombined= {{
   {{0, t, q, dh}, 
    {0, 1, 0, th}, 
    {1, 0, 1, sh}}},
   {{{0, t, q, dh}, 
    {1, 1, 1, th}, 
    {1, 0, 0, sh}}
           }}
```

and with thanks to Kgular [getting-good-looking-matrix..](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51659/getting-good-looking-matrix-form-output-from-a-matrix-having-both-scalars-and-ma)I could add a vector `m` as:

```
m = {rr, kk}
```

to the *ncombined* as bellow:

```
pp = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[ncombined], Flatten@m, 1]];
ppgoodlook=MapAt[MatrixForm, pp, {{All, All}, {}}]
```

[image]

I am so sorry if my question maybe will not well written while I have so much tried to write it more obviously. Also I will bring the image of the desired result.

question:
Since, number `1` is not repeated in the same elements of `a` and `b`
, also for `c` and `d`, how can I refer each of `1` in the `ppgoodlook` to the main sub_matrices such as `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` (from which, `1` is gone to `ppgoodlook`) in order to obtain the bellow result (However this referring is regardless to the letters of sub_matrices such as `sh`,`th`, `q`, `t` and `dh`) :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ncombined = {{{{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 1, sh}}},
              {{{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 1, 1, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}};
pos = Join @@ (Thread[{Position[#1, 1], #2}] & @@@ 
     Thread[{{a, b, c, d}, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}]);
pos = pos /. {{{x_, y_}, p : "a" | "b"} :> {{1, 1, x, y},  p}, 
              {{x_, y_}, p : "c" | "d"} :> {{2, 1, x, y}, p}};
ncombined2 = ncombined;
(ncombined2[[Sequence @@ #[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ pos;
m = {rr, kk};
pp2 = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[ncombined2], Flatten@m, 1]];
ppgoodlook2 = MapAt[MatrixForm, pp2, {{All, All}, {}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer, Should you extend your answer to a general problem. I mean if we do not know the exact palace of 'a' and 'b' also, 'c' and 'd'. you separated, a and b, c and d in the line:                 pos = pos /. {{{x_, y_}, p : "a" | "b"} :> {{1, 1, x, y},  p}, 
              {{x_, y_}, p : "c" | "d"} :> {{2, 1, x, y}, p}};                                                        But if we have d in the topmost sub_matrices near the a and b, what must we do?